# Procedural way to generate signal combinations and their output in r

Tags: r

I have been continuing to learn r to transition away from excel and I am wondering what the best way to approach the following problem is, or at least what tools are available to me:

I have a large data set (100K+ rows) and several columns that I could generate a signal off of and each value in the vectors can range between 0 and 3.

```
   sig1 sig2 sig3 sig4 
    1   1   1   1
    1   1   1   1
    1   0   1   1
    1   0   1   1
    0   0   1   1
    0   1   2   2
    0   1   2   2
    0   1   1   2
    0   1   1   2
```

I want to generate composite signals using the state of each cell in the four columns then see what each of the composite signals tell me about the returns in a time series. For this question the scope is only generating the combinations.

So for example, one composite signal would be when all four cells in the vectors = 0. I could generate a new column that reads TRUE when that case is true and false in each other case, then go on to figure out how that effects the returns from the rest of the data frame.

The thing is I want to check all combinations of the four columns, so 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003 and on and on, which is quite a few. With the extent of my knowledge of r, I only know how to do that by using `mutate()` for each combination and explicitly entering the condition to check. I assume there is a better way to do this, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could paste the columns together to get unique combinations, then just turn this to dummy variables:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dummies)

# Create sample data
data <- data.frame(sig1 = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
                   sig2 = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1),
                   sig3 = c(2,2,0,1,1,2,1))

# Paste together
data <- data %>% mutate(sig_tot = paste0(sig1,sig2,sig3))

# Generate dummmies
data <- cbind(data, dummy(data$sig_tot, sep = "_"))

# Turn to logical if needed
data <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(contains("data_")), as.logical)  
data
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. There is so much to learn! Thanks dude!

Comment: So one issue I did run into is that I want to exclude generating colums when one or more of those signals is 0. so if sig1 = 0, the don't generate a column.  Will be looking into how to do this.